# Why are UFW rules bak'd when start on boot is enabled?

Tags: debian, ufw

Yesterday I noticed the firewall was down for my Debian server (Buster, 2020-10) and all of my rules were no longer present (as per `$ sudo ufw status`). *Ok. Lesson learned.*

At first I thought the rules were lost. There was a similar post at AskUbuntu, [UFW rules disappear after manually adding them to user.rules ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/1071555/441986)

> "If you add your custom rules in /etc/ufw/before*.rules or
> after*.rules instead, it will not disappear after a reload. [p] When
> valid ufw commands are entered on the shell, i.e., custom user rules,
> they go into /etc/ufw/user*.rules files, and those persist."

Ok. My rules were indeed saved, but also bak'd with datetime, and therefore unloaded.

```
$ cd /etc/ufw                                                                                                         
$ ls                                                                                                          
applications.d/               after.rules.20210307_140833    before.rules.20210307_140833  user.rules
after6.rules                  before6.rules                  sysctl.conf                   user.rules.20210307_140833
after6.rules.20210307_140833  before6.rules.20210307_140833  ufw.conf
after.init                    before.init                    user6.rules
after.rules                   before.rules                   user6.rules.20210307_140833
```

**Why are rules bak'd if restart on boot is enabled? What mechanism is bak'ing old rules and creating new empty rule configs when the expected behavior is to use the current rules??**

```
# /etc/ufw/ufw.conf
#
ufw allow from 192.168.1.101 to any port 22
# Set to yes to start on boot. If setting this remotely, be sure to add a rule
# to allow your remote connection before starting ufw. Eg: 'ufw allow 22/tcp'
ENABLED=yes
```

Comment: "bak'd"? What do you mean by "bak'd"?

Comment: Because Linux is a file-based system, you can just rename a conf with `*.bak` and essentially keep it from loading. So when I see all of my configs renamed with what I assume was the crash date `20210307`, they are essentially prevented from loading. If there is an official term then let's change it.

Comment: `rules bak'd` sounds weird, this is my first time hearing it (i tried to google it, no result found except this post). Is it about "rules are backed up"?